# Pass a values from a tab delimited file to Google Maps object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass Latitude and Longitude values to the Google map's object from the printInfo function. I'm loading in a tab delimited file and I can grab the values from it with no issue, but I'm stuck on how to pass it to the initMap function to give it to the center object.  Should I be using a callback function to pass the values through? If so, I'm not 100% how to do that. I tried creating a Global variable but it didn't seem to work.

```
function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapProp =  {
      center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv,mapProp);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initMap);


//Load in tab delimited file
d3.text("ix_cities.tmpl", function(text){

    printInfo(text);
 });


//print out the info in the console
//I'm trying to pass the Lat/Long values to the google map API
function printInfo(text) {
   var info = d3.tsv.parseRows(text);
    console.log(info);

    var infoLen = info.length;

    console.log("Cities file Length: " + infoLen);

    for(var i = 0; i < infoLen; i++ ){

        console.log("Title: " + info[i][0]);
        console.log("Street Address: " + info[i][1]);
        console.log("City & ZIP: " + info[i][2]);
        console.log("Phone Number: " + info[i][3]);
        console.log("Lat: "  + info[i][4]);
        console.log("Long: " + info[i][5]);
        console.log("URL: " + info[i][6]);
    } 



}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with the values?

Comment: Well I want to pass them into  here  

var mapProp =  {
      center: {lat: VAL1 lng: VAL2},
      zoom: 8
    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are bad. Use namespacing.

```
(function(myMaps) {    
    var map;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    myMaps.initMap = function() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapProp = {
            center: { lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546 },
            zoom: 8
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapProp);
    }
    myMaps.center = function(lat, lng) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    }
}(window.myMaps = window.myMaps || {}));
```

Now call `myMaps.center` from anywhere else in js. Pass `Latitude`. `Longitude` and map will center to that location. You can even defer the map initialization by removing the `addDomListener` and calling `initMap` after reading the csv. Add `lat/lng` arguments to `initMap`.

Some typos. Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvvu4r4L/1/).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I did move the event listener out of the namespace and then the map loads, but when I call myMaps.center  and pass it the Lat/Long, the map doesn't change to reflect the coordinates.

Comment: When I try and call myMaps.center, it says in the console that setCenter is undefined, which is weird.

Comment: weird. can you try panTo. `map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng))`

Comment: It also says that is undefined :/

Comment: Oh awesome! That does work to change the lat/long but the function I'm calling it in doesn't seem to work. Its the callback function for loading in the file. I'll have to figure it out why, but it does set outside of that function. Thank you for your help!